# Laravel Linux storage:link doesn't remain storage's content

Tags: php, linux, laravel

I'm in Ubuntu OS and when i try to run `php artisan storage:link`, it links the folder but here is the thing; actual linked `public/storage` doesn't contain original `storage`'s content. How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if php artisan storage:link doesnt fix your problem, try to make your own symlink manually.

```
ln -s [your actual storage directory] [your symlink destination]
```

for example

```
ln -s storage/app/public public/storage
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the public disk uses the local driver and stores its files in `storage/app/public`

To make these files accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` and the command is  `php artisan storage:link`